# Unclosed Character Literal error while writing an integer data in a file

Tags: java, arrays, file, filereader, filewriter

I tried to write Integer data to my file using java.io.FileWriter it shows me

```
error: unclosed character literal
```

the error line:

```
        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("fw.txt");
        fw.write(new char[]{'10','20','30'});
        fw.flush();
```

but when I try to write an character in the file using character array, there's no problem with the literals.

Trying to Read and Write integer data in a file only using java.io.BufferedReader.

Comment: A character literal is a single character, e.g. '1', not two characters like '10'

Comment: What do you want to do? In Java the various `Writer` classes are used to write sequences of characters (i.e. Strings or character arrays). To write integer data you need to convert it into characters first.